# How to lookup NAT Gateway by the tag name in AWS CDK

Tags: python, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc, aws-nat-gateway

I am trying to whitelist the public IP of the NAT gateway that the VPC uses in the API Gateway resource policy of the lambda function. My AWS Account has a NAT Gateway which is already a part of the VPC. My main goal is to be able to get the public IP address of the NAT Gateway.

I am using `fromLookup()` to import VPC into the cdk.

I've looked through was documentation and noticed that NAT Gateway construct doesn't have the `fromLookup()` method. Also tried to access NAT Gateway through VPC attributes but seems like it's not there.
This post seems promising: ([stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71976434/how-to-list-all-the-nat-gateway-in-a-vpc-via-cdk)), but I can't figure out how to implement the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed impossible to look up existing NAT GW using `fromLookup()`.

What you will have to do is combine CDK and SDK.

What you need to do is install SDK :`npm install aws-sdk`

And then use `getNATGatewayPublicIP()` function to fetch the public IP.